# Mouse/Keyboard stop responding for short time at random intervals - OSX v10.10, 13 inch MaBookPro Retina

Tags: performance

my whole computer freezes it seems like, if I have streaming music playing it continues, however my mouse and keyboard stop working. This includes the trackpad and laptop keyboard not just my peripheral mouse and keyboard.

OSX v10.10, 13 inch MaBookPro Retina
16GB Memory 
3Ghz i7 processor.

Any help appreciated, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

There have been bugs reported with certain OSX Operating systems regarding your issue. There are a multitude of things you can do.

1. Update the OSX on your computer.

2. If the OSX is updated, try uninstalled that OSX and re-installing it. Sometimes there are issues with typical functions when the computer is being installed or updated.

3. Try switching accounts, often times there are some circumstances that have altered the settings on your computer. In such a case, create a new account and test if it is doing the same thing.

4. If none of these solutions have helped, your computer may have a manufactures default and I suggest you take it to your nearest Apple Store or Certified apple care specialist.

I hope this could be of help.

If this helped you, please accept the answer so that it can help the community find this answer if they are having the same issue as you.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow thanks for the help. I have work with it tonight hopefully it holds up!